# How to align the canvas object to center of the screen?

Tags: android, layout, canvas

I am making a screen where i need my gBall to align at the center of the screen.
The code is as follows.

```
  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);

    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    textPaint.setTextSize(canvas.getWidth() / 7);
    textPaint.setTypeface(font);
    canvas.drawText("MY Text", (canvas.getWidth() / 2),
            (float) (canvas.getHeight() * 0.75), textPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gball, 0, (float) (canvas.getHeight() * .25), null);//This is where i need help
}
```

But i am getting it aligned to left of the screen, can anyone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it right wth this code!

```
  canvas.drawBitmap(gball, (canvas.getWidth()/2-(gball.getWidth()/2)), (float) (canvas.getHeight() * .25), null);
```

Answer (score 4):

You get it at the left of the screen because your X value is set to 0. It should be

```
   int startX= (canvas.getWidth()-gBall.getWidth())/2;//for horisontal position
   int startY=(canvas.getHeight()-gBall.getHeight())/2;//for vertical position
   canvas.drawBitmap(gball, startX, startY, null);
```

Also, do not initialize your paint in onDraw() method.

Comment: with canvas.getHeigh()*0.25 you will not get your bitmap vertical centered