# How to add padding completely around a bitmap programmatically?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I'm trying to add padding to a bitmap programmatically however, when I add the padding to the top, it's removed from the bottom. When I add it to the bottom, it's removed from the top.

Adding padding to the top

[image]

```
Bitmap backgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) backgroundDrawable).getBitmap();


            int padding = 60;

            int positionLeft = 0;
            int positionTop = 0;
            Bitmap mainBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    backgroundBitmap.getWidth(), //Adding top padding here
                    backgroundBitmap.getHeight() + padding,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            );
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mainBitmap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(
                    backgroundBitmap,
                    positionLeft + padding,
                    positionTop + padding,
                    null
            );
```

Adding padding to the bottom removes the top padding

```
 Bitmap backgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) backgroundDrawable).getBitmap();


            int padding = 60;

            int positionLeft = 0;
            int positionTop = 0;
            Bitmap mainBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    backgroundBitmap.getWidth(),
                    backgroundBitmap.getHeight() + padding,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            );
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mainBitmap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(
                    backgroundBitmap,
                    positionLeft + padding,
                    positionTop, //Adding bottom padding here
                    null
            );
```

[image]

Can't figure out

how can I add padding to all 4 sides to my `backgroundBitmap` bitmap?

**Edit1:____________________________________________**

I've also tried this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15525394/11110509

which adds a border to the bitmap, however it's only adding the border to the top and left. Doesn't include the bottom and right

```
private Bitmap addWhiteBorder(Bitmap bmp, int borderSize) {
    Bitmap bmpWithBorder = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getHeight() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpWithBorder);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, borderSize, borderSize, null);
    return bmpWithBorder;
}
```

```
Bitmap backgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) backgroundDrawable).getBitmap();


            int padding = 60;

            int positionLeft = 0;
            int positionTop = 0;
            Bitmap mainBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    backgroundBitmap.getWidth(),
                    backgroundBitmap.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            );
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mainBitmap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(
                    addWhiteBorder(backgroundBitmap, padding),
                    positionLeft,
                    positionTop,
                    null
            );
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not help you but don't pad the Bitmap, add it to a container in the view like a linearlayout and then pad the linearlayout . It should be a lot easier to deal with.

```
int left = (canvas.getWidth()-mainBitmap.getWidth())/2;
int top = (canvas.getHeight()-mainBitmap.getHeight())/2;
canvas.drawBitmap(mainBitmap, left, top, null);
```

This should get the the bitmap to the center in relation to the canvas.
I got it from here if you need more info [How to align the canvas object to center of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237016/how-to-align-the-canvas-object-to-center-of-the-screen)

Comment: I can't use that in my case because I need the entire bitmap. If I try to convert the bitmap that I added to a view, back to a bitmap, it'll be small when I save it to my app's photo directory.

Comment: I've also tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15525394/11110509 which adds a border to the bitmap, however it's only adding the border to the top and left. Doesn't include the bottom and right. https://i.imgur.com/ILunzSl.png

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was that I didn't have enough padding space in my main Bitmap

```
            Bitmap backgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) backgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
            Bitmap appLogoBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) appLogoDrawable).getBitmap();

            int padding = 60;

            int positionLeft = 0;
            int positionTop = 0;
            Bitmap mainBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    backgroundBitmap.getWidth() + (padding * 2), //Adding the * 2 helped display the padding
                    backgroundBitmap.getHeight()  + (padding * 2),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            );
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mainBitmap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(
                    addWhiteBorder(backgroundBitmap, padding),
                    positionLeft,
                    positionTop,
                    null
            );
```

And the function to add the padding:

```
private Bitmap addWhiteBorder(Bitmap bmp, int borderSize) {
        Bitmap bmpWithBorder = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getHeight() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpWithBorder);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#63A4FF"));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, borderSize, borderSize, null);
        return bmpWithBorder;
    }
```